# Advanced NSOperation - Add dependency at runtime

Tags: ios, swift, dependencies, nsoperation

Is there a way to create an `NSoperation` at run time and add it as a dependency to an operation which is in progress and already in execute state?

If not, Is there any other alternative way to achieve this?

For example (use case where I need this):

Based on the response from server, I want to initiate a new `NSOperation`, whereas the web service itself is driven by a connection operation (which is already in progress ).

Now I want the connection operation to finish only after this response driven `NSOperation` finishes.

Reference from where I took the code:

https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2015/

Sample Code : Advanced NSOperations

**Note :**

1. One option is that, I can alway add this NSOperation as a dependency and call finish if that response is not present in response. But still, my point is that I do not want to invoke that operation at all if I don't get that response.
2. Another option is having this Connection  operation to wait till that operation completes and then call finish() of this response driven `NSOperation` (This is indirect way of achieving the solution).
3. The reason why I am trying to execute it in run time is that I want that module including that `NSOperation` to be pluggable from my project. When ever I don't want the module.. I shall remove the files and it should not affect the system.

Just wanted to know if some one came across the same scenario.

Comment: You can create an NSBlockOperation is basically a block wrapped around an NSOperation, there is also NSInvocationOperation. Of course they do support dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can't attach dependencies to running NSOperations, and even if you could, it would not do much. The dependencies prevent their NSOperation from starting until all of them are finished, after the operation is already started there's no point left to them.

I'm sorry but I don't understand your use case. Could you clarify what your "connection operation" is ? Also, what would you expect to happen when attaching a new dependency to it ? Should it stop running ?

Comment: It is not supposed to stop running. It is supposed to wait until, the next operation which is been created based on the web service response finishes. Connection operation as it says is the operation being used to connect to web service (ideally a url connection, followed by parsing which is dependent on network operation).  I know if a dependency is being added, the operation will wait to start until the dependencies finish. I was just wondering if there is some work around which can make the running operation wait if dependencies are added at runtime.